# Python Pygame, Raspberry Pi with GPS navigation function

Tags: python, gps, pygame, raspberry-pi

I'm using a Raspberry Pi and i'm working on a car computer project. I'm building the interface with pygame, and the thougt of a GPS system just hit me and would be awesome. So I'm just checking if this some how is possible, or if someone knows about a similar project.

I've spent some time googeling but not found anything that's interesting. I know that  Google maps has a pretty neat GPS service, but then i would need to have some kind of web browser in my pygame project to render the maps - I guess there's nothing like this, huh?

Maybe I could reach the Google API some how and just get the directions and all that but no maps. That is, just display text with "in 200 meters turn right" for example. Not spent any time checking it out, I thougt it was best to check for ideas and tips here first.

Has enyone else done anything similar to this? Any good tips or ideas? Streamed or locally stored maps does not matter. The Pi will have internet access through wifi to hotspot on my phone. (Yes, it's easier to just let the phone guide me, but tere's no fun in that.)

Answer (score -1):

modRana looks promising.  It's GPS software for Linux devices.

[Modrana Trac](http://modrana.org/trac)

[Screenshots](http://modrana.org/trac/wiki/ScreenshotsENscreesnhot)

Please update if you manage to use it - I'm working on a similiar idea (battery powered raspberry pi + PiTFT + gps + a copule sensors, all run by pygame)